# Two JPanels instead of one

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I tried to create a JFrame and put 5 JPanels on it.
The problem is, that the top panel appears twice.
This is the Frame class:

```
package Chess;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import Chess.NorthPanel;
public class Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawpanels();
    }
public static void drawpanels() {
    JFrame board=new JFrame("Board");
    board.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    board.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    board.setVisible(true);
    board.setSize(1000, 1000);
    board.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(224,224,224));
    
    NorthPanel p1=new NorthPanel();
    SouthPanel p2=new SouthPanel(); 
    CenterPanel p3=new CenterPanel();
    JPanel p4=new JPanel();
    JPanel p5=new JPanel();

    p4.setBackground(Color.green);
    p5.setBackground(Color.red);
        
    board.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    board.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    board.add(p3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    board.add(p4, BorderLayout.EAST);
    board.add(p5, BorderLayout.WEST);
    board.validate();
    }   
}
```

And this is the NorthPanel class:

```
package Chess;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NorthPanel extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public NorthPanel() {
    this.setBackground(new Color(128,128,128));
    JLabel label=new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/rlt.png"));
    this.add(label);
    }
}
```

(There are two other classes for SouthPanel and CenterPanel.)

And the result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXBon.png]

Why are there two rooks?
What other problems are there with this code?

Comment: Try making `board.setVisible(true);` the last line in method `drawpanels()`.

Comment: Swing components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible (as suggested by Abra). However, the problem could also be in your custom classes, especially if you are doing custom painting and are not invoking `super.paintComponent(...)`. For future reference, if you have a dynamic GUI and add components to the frame after it is visible then you should use `revalidate()` and `repaint()`.

Comment: Thank you, both answers were useful, thanks!

Comment: *"Thank you"* Tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Note that only one person can be tagged in a comment. To thank two people, make two comments.